# Creating a GUI that will graph CPU usage in Linux

Tags: c, linux, user-interface, cpu-usage

I want to write a GUI that graphs CPU usage in real time. My goal was to be able to run a program from the GUI, and then once the program has started, a graph of the CPU usage would run that would illustrate how the program was using CPU resources. What's the simplest way of doing something like this? I'm developing on Linux, and am aware of tools like (h)top and mpstat.

EDIT: I should be a bit more descriptive, sorry. How can I get something like CPU usage from top, and redirect it to a GUI that illustrates it into a graph  form in real time?

Comment: Unless you ask a specific question, your post will likely be closed. Stack Overflow is about answering specific programming questions, not teaching you to program from scratch. We can't reasonably answer this.

Comment: Did you try konky? It supports LUA too! Not exactly what you are searching for but still!

Comment: For measuring CPU usage: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1420426/calculating-cpu-usage-of-a-process-in-linux

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check out Qt framework. Qt has really good support GUI development on Linux.