# cpu usage per process?

Tags: linux, performance

How can I grab the percentage of cpu usage on a per process basis? So, for example, I'd like to run my program `prog` and get the cpu usage it incurred in, for example:

```
  prog name cpu0 cpu1 cpu2 cpu3  total
  prog        15   20   45   47   127%
```

Is there any tool for this?
Thanks.

Comment: Is `top` sufficient for your purposes?

Comment: Oli, hi. Problem with `top` is that it is too "dynamic" if you will, for my purposes. I need something like the linux `time` command, reporting cpu usage about that process only.

Comment: Ok, that kind of sounds like you want to know what %age of all cycles used by your process were run on CPU0, CPU1, etc.?  In which case, what does 127% mean in your example above?

Comment: Ah, that's just the aggregate over all cpus. So for 4 cores (the example above), the process used an aggregate of 127% over 400% max. Does that make sense?

Comment: So are you saying that 400% would equate to all 4 CPUs fully utilised by your app measured across its total runtime?

Comment: This might help you out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1420426/calculating-cpu-usage-of-a-process-in-linux

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[linux process explorer](http://sourceforge.net/projects/procexp/) project provides this functionality, you can see a graph for the CPU/Memory/IO for each process in the properties dialog.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I think that you can make use of the information in `/proc/[pid]/stat` and `/proc/stat` to estimate this.

Check out the great answers to [How to calculate the CPU usage of a process by PID in Linux from C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1420426/calculating-cpu-usage-of-a-process-in-linux) which explain how to calculate CPU usage % for a single processor.

The 6th from last number you get from `/proc/[pid]/stat` is "processor %d, CPU number last executed on" (on Ubuntu 12.04 at least).

To extend to multiple processors, you could sample the CPU usage over a period and (very roughly!) estimate the proportion of time on each processor. Then use these proportions to split the CPU usage between the processors. Based on the info in `/proc/stat` you can also sample the total time for each processor and then you have all the variables you need!

See http://linux.die.net/man/5/proc for more info about proc.

Answer (score 1):

For firefox:

```
while [ 1 ]; do ps --no-heading -C firefox -L -o command,psr,pcpu|sort -k 2 -n; echo; sleep 1; done
```

You'd have to sum the third column (which I see no ridiculously easy way to do) because it's actually showing you every thread.  First column is name, second processor, third, %cpu.

Comment: awk can grab you the third column with $3 I believe, I forget the syntax for it :\

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple python i've made:

```
import re,time,sys
cpuNum=0
if len(sys.argv)==1:
    print "use pidcpu <pid1,pid2,..,pidn>"
    sys.exit(0)

pids=sys.argv.pop()

def getCpuTot():
    global cpuNum
    f=open("/proc/stat","r")
    ln=f.read()
    f.close()
    #cpu  858286704 148088 54216880 117129864 2806189 5046 16997674 0 0 0
    r=re.findall("cpu[\d\s]{1}\s+(\d+)\s(\d+)\s(\d+)\s(\d+)\s.*?",ln,re.DOTALL)
    cpuNum=len(r)-1
    return int(r[0][0])+int(r[0][1])+int(r[0][2])+int(r[0][3])

def getPidCPU(pid):
    f=open("/proc/"+ str(pid) +"/stat","r")
    ln=f.readline()
    f.close()
    a=ln.split(" ")
    return int(a[13])+int(a[14])

cpu1=getCpuTot()
cpupid1=[]
for pid in pids.split(","):
    cpupid1.append(getPidCPU(pid))
time.sleep(1)
cpu2=getCpuTot()    
cpupid2=[]
for pid in pids.split(","):
    cpupid2.append(getPidCPU(pid))


i=0
for pid in pids.split(","):
    perc=int(cpuNum*(cpupid2[i]-cpupid1[i])*100/float(cpu2-cpu1))
    i+=1
    print pid,perc
```