# Get the CPU usage for a process in Java

Tags: java, linux, jboss

I need to get the CPU usage fro a particular process from java code in LINUX.

I tried

> Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("top");

or

> Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("top | grep java");

But It's not returning any thing. Actually I want to get the CPU usages of several JBOSS nodes. If I can "top" or something inside the java code then I can process the out put an find the details that I want.

But if I try

> Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ls -l");

Its returning the out put correctly.

Is there I can do like this or are there any other options to do this?

thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/47177/how-to-monitor-the-computers-cpu-memory-and-disk-usage-in-java

Answer (score 2):

If you know the process IDs, and you are the user that started them (or you've got sufficient privilege) you could always get the details by reading the pseudo-file /proc/**PID**/stat. There's a good description of how to do this in answer to this question: [How to calculate the CPU usage of a process by PID in Linux from C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1420426/calculating-cpu-usage-of-a-process-in-linux).

Comment: Yes this is a good way. But the problem is I have to know the PID already. for that I had to do an another system call. But many thanks for the link

Answer (score 0):

This should work I believe...

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ps -ao pcpu,args | grep java");
```

or `top -b | grep java` if you insist on using `top`

Comment: No this is not working. Command line it's working but not in the java code.

Comment: How exactly is it not working? Do you get any output? Have you tried both of my suggestions?

Comment: Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("top -b | grep java");
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

while ((s = in.readLine()) != null) {
   System.out.println(s);
}


Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ps -ao pcpu,args | grep java");
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

while ((s = in.readLine()) != null) {
   System.out.println(s);
}   But no any out put

Comment: can you check the error stream to see if you have any errors returned? I am not sure you can run all commands with exec as some require the shell to be running first. to get the error stream do : BufferedReader err= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getErrorStream())); and then print from it. to run a shell and then the command in it, try Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] {"bash","-c","top | grep java" } );   you can also replace the last argument in the array with the command given in this answer.

Comment: for : BufferedReader err= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getErrorStream()));  >>  TERM environment variable not set.

Comment: did you try running with array of parameters? also I suggest you should change the title of the question as this is more related to java exec that getting a process cpu usage.

Comment: How can I run with array of parameters ?