# Measuring CPU% of apps, should I extrapolate?

Tags: linux

I am running a linux process which does the following

1. Reads all the numeric file names from */proc*
2. For each, it reads the `utime` and `stime` from */proc/pid/stat*

Now the complete loop takes say starts at `t0` time and finishes at `t1` time.
`t1-t0` can be of an order of seconds on a slow processor if number of processes are more...

So Is it right to extrapolate `utime` and `stime` ? If yes how should I go about?

Or is there any better way? I dont know how `top` command does it?

I am trying to create something like a top command.

Answer (score 0):

http://colby.id.au/calculating-cpu-usage-from-proc-stat

You want to read it twice, and use the differences.

Also, remember that there are many different places time can go (for example Steal time). Your numbers won't always add up to 100% if you don't account for all of them.

Comment: The sample code in the link does cat /proc/stat. What I was targetting is /proc/[pid]/stat

Comment: Yup, the same recommendation applies. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1420426/calculating-cpu-usage-of-a-process-in-linux

Comment: How should I extrapolate