# Find cpu time of a process and it children while the process is still running

Tags: c, linux, bash, cpu, cpu-usage

I have a bash script which runs a series of programs which run other programs . How would I  get the cpu time of the bash script and **all**  of it descendants processes.

I looked in /proc/{process-id}/stat  and the question [How to calculate the CPU usage of a process by PID in Linux from C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1420426/calculating-cpu-usage-of-a-process-in-linux)

but I am not sure how I would calculate the total cpu time for all the child processes of the bash script.

Edit 
If I calculate difference in utime  and difference in stime for some time interval, I know for a single process the cpu time (utime + stime) it took in that interval.

How would I add up the cpu time for all the child processes (which also create their own processes) while the process is still running?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can calculate it using the:

> **utime %lu**
>
> Amount of time that this process has been scheduled in user mode,
>   measured in clock ticks (divide by sysconf(_SC_CLK_TCK). This includes
>   guest time, guest_time (time spent running a virtual CPU, see below),
>   so that applications that are not aware of the guest time field do not
>   lose that time from their calculations.
>
> **stime %lu**
>
> Amount of time that this process has been scheduled in kernel mode,
>   measured in clock ticks (divide by sysconf(_SC_CLK_TCK).
>
> **cutime %ld**
>
> Amount of time that this process's waited-for children have been
>   scheduled in user mode, measured in clock ticks (divide by
>   sysconf(_SC_CLK_TCK). (See also times(2).) This includes guest time,
>   cguest_time (time spent running a virtual CPU, see below).
>
> **cstime %ld**
>
> Amount of time that this process's waited-for children have been
>   scheduled in kernel mode, measured in clock ticks (divide by
>   sysconf(_SC_CLK_TCK).

Comment: These times don't seems to include the cpu of the children, e.g  if the bash script run another script which ran java looking at  /proc/{bash-script-process-id}/stat does seem to include the cpu time of the java process, how would get the cpu time of all the children?

Comment: You mention several times to see below, are you referring to cstime?

Comment: On the top level script the utime, cutime, stime are 0 whereas the the utime and stime of the child java process are 29007 and 192, and the  child java process's cstime is 0.  The process is still running

Comment: @Bilal were you able to find some way eventually?

Comment: @pranavk I wrote a C program that looked into /proc and added the cpu time of the program and it subprocess

Comment: Yeah, that is what came to my mind too, but I was wondering if there is any inbuilt way to find it for a process + its children in one shot just like it is already there for process + terminated children. Anyways, I will go this way then.