# get cpu time of an external process and it children while it still running on OS X

Tags: c, linux, macos, timing, cpu-time

On linux I can use `/proc` as stated in [How to calculate the CPU usage of a process by PID in Linux from C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1420426/calculating-cpu-usage-of-a-process-in-linux) to get the cpu time of a  process and it children.

How would I do this on OS X?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get process information using [sysctl](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/sysctl.3.html). So, let's assume that you have the pid for a process: -

```
#include <sys/sysctl.h>

struct kinfo_proc *getProcessInfo(pid_t pid)
{
    struct kinfo_proc* list = NULL;

    int mib[] = {CTL_KERN, KERN_PROC, KERN_PROC_PID, pid};
    size_t size = 0;

    sysctl(mib, sizeof(mib) / sizeof(*mib), NULL, &size, NULL, 0);

    list = (kinfo_proc*)malloc(size);
    sysctl(mib, sizeof(mib) / sizeof(*mib), list, &size, NULL, 0);

    return list;
}
```

Remember to check for errors returned from sysctl. I've left them out for brevity and don't forget to free the returned structure when you're finished with it.

The returned **kinfo_proc** structure contains a structure **extern_proc**, which you will see has the following attributes: -

```
struct extern_proc {
    union {
        struct {
            struct  proc *__p_forw; /* Doubly-linked run/sleep queue. */
            struct  proc *__p_back;
        } p_st1;
        struct timeval __p_starttime;   /* process start time */
    } p_un;

    ....
}
```

**__p_starttime**, is what you're looking for.