# How to calculate CPU utilization for all running processes in linux using "proc" file system?

Tags: c, linux, cpu-usage

From [This](https://github.com/fho/code_snippets/blob/master/c/getusage.c) and [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1420426/calculating-cpu-usage-of-a-process-in-linux) i am trying to calculate CPU utilization but it is not coming as expected. **(i.e.** 
My application is showing CPU utilization as 3% and top is showing 99%.)

I am trying below method,

```
usage=100*(((utime_ticks_current + cutime_ticks_current + stime_ticks_current + cstime_ticks_current) - (utime_ticks_prev + cutime_ticks_prev + stime_ticks_prev + cstime_ticks_prev)) / (long)(total_cpu_time_current - total_cpu_time_prev))

here, 
utime_ticks = /proc/pid/stat -> 14th value
stime_ticks = /proc/pid/stat -> 15th value
cutime_ticks = /proc/pid/stat -> 16th value
cstime_ticks = /proc/pid/stat -> 17th value

total_cpu_time = /proc/stat -> sum of all 10 values
```

Time difference between current and prev is 1 second.

Also, I have manually checked that all the values for all the variables are correct only.

Please note that i tried the same thing separately for **"stime , cstime" and "utime , cutime"**

I think there is some problem in the way i am calculating it,

Can anyone please help?

---

I only found the solution, I just had to multiply the value with total number of Cores/CPU available.

---

Comment: So do you want to get cpu usage for a single process, or average cpu usage for a moment in time?

Comment: I want to calculate cpu utilization in % for all the process running on system

Answer (score 0):

I can give you part of the code I use for my cpu utilization server. It is very accurate.

```
long double a[4], b[4], loadavg;
FILE *fp;
char dump[50] = {0};
memset(dump, 0, 50);

fp = fopen("/proc/stat","r");
fscanf(fp,"%*s %Lf %Lf %Lf %Lf",&a[0],&a[1],&a[2],&a[3]);
fclose(fp);
sleep(1);

fp = fopen("/proc/stat","r");
fscanf(fp,"%*s %Lf %Lf %Lf %Lf",&b[0],&b[1],&b[2],&b[3]);
fclose(fp);

loadavg = ((b[0]+b[1]+b[2]) - (a[0]+a[1]+a[2])) / ((b[0]+b[1]+b[2]+b[3]) - (a[0]+a[1]+a[2]+a[3]));
loadavg=loadavg*100;
sprintf(dump, "%Lf\n",loadavg);
long double used;
```

Comment: Thank you, but i want to calculate CPU utilization for each process,i think above code will give CPU utilization for each core.