# Frequency scaling and CPU utilization

Tags: linux, cpu-usage

There are quite a few questions here on StackOverflow explaining how to calculate process CPU utilization (e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1420426/how-to-calculate-the-cpu-usage-of-a-process-by-pid-in-linux-from-c/1424556#1424556)). What I don't understand is how frequency scaling affects CPU utilization calculations.  It seems to me, if I follow the formula recommended (and I actually also checked top's source code and it does the same), a process running on a CPU at the lowest frequency and a process running at the highest CPU frequency for the same duration will yield identical utilization rate.  But this doesn't feel right to me, especially when CPU utilization is used as a stand-in to compare power consumption.

What am I missing?